# KYPO Deployment failure openstack retuning no valid host found

Tags: security, openstack, devstack

I have deployed devstack for my OpenStack using the default configuration and trying to deploy kypo. I am running ./create-base.sh and getting the following error

[kypo-proxy-jump-stack]: CREATE_FAILED  Resource CREATE failed: ResourceInError: resources.kypo-proxy-jump: Went to status ERROR due to "Message: No valid host was found. , Code: 500"
[kypo-proxy-jump-stack.kypo-proxy-jump]: CREATE_FAILED  ResourceInError: resources.kypo-proxy-jump: Went to status ERROR due to "Message: No valid host was found. , Code: 500"

**My devstack config:**
**content of local.conf**

```
[[local|localrc]]

#Enable heat services
enable_service h-eng h-api h-api-cfn h-api-cw


[[local|localrc]]

#Enable heat plugin
enable_plugin heat https://opendev.org/openstack/heat

IMAGE_URL_SITE="https://download.fedoraproject.org"
IMAGE_URL_PATH="/pub/fedora/linux/releases/33/Cloud/x86_64/images/"
IMAGE_URL_FILE="Fedora-Cloud-Base-33-1.2.x86_64.qcow2"
IMAGE_URLS+=","$IMAGE_URL_SITE$IMAGE_URL_PATH$IMAGE_URL_FILE
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround: you need to reduce the kypo-proxy-jump's flavor.

Something like this:

```
openstack flavor create --ram 2048 --disk 10 --vcpus 1 standard.medium
```

However, check your Openstack resources and logs, there is probably lack of resource (disk, mem or cpu).